# XMPP SMACK file receiving not working on android

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, smack, asmack

I am unable to recive the file, which I am transfering from SPARK client.
I am using ASMACK jar Library so it's not possible to get into the library.

```
ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    if (sdm == null){
        sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
    } 

//  new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, false);
    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
    manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
        public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
            Log.d("", "allows file...");
            if (request != null) {
                // Accept it
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                try {

                   // String pathsd =    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                    String path = "/sdcard/"+ request.getFileName();
                    transfer.recieveFile(new File(path));

                    // transfer.recieveFile(new
                    // File(request.getFileName()));
                     System.out.println("File " + request.getFileName() + "Received Successfully");
    //                      Log.d("", "rece: " +    request.getFileName());                     
    //                      Log.d("", "path: " + request.getFileName());
                    // InputStream input = transfer.recieveFile();
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.d("", "er: " + ex);
                }
               } else {
                Log.d("", "reject file...");
                request.reject();
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: are you able to send file i got an error service unavailable 503

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what version of Smack your asmack is based on, but there is a [known issue with file transfer](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-351) in Smack, which both asmack and Spark are based on.

Comment: I m using beem project amsack library they had patched version. It works fine but file transfer is not happening...

Answer (score 0):

Beems asmack build process is [well documented](http://www.beem-project.com/projects/beem/repository/entry/doc/asmack-beem/README.txt) and also the sources are open for everyone.

Your code looks right, but why do you set this

```
FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, false);
```

to false?

File transfer in XMPP is a rather complex topic. There are various methods (at least 4), to get a file from one resource to another. As you provided no further details I can only give you general device on how to debug this:

[Enable connection debug in smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Connection.html#DEBUG_ENABLED), which will **print out and log all XMPP packets that go in and out.** Trace the XMPP stanzas that relate to the file transfer and make sure they behave as specified in the XEPs. This may provides a hint about whats going wrong.